# Method for transfer current iPhone Wi-Fi settings to a iP-camera without MFI enrollment

Tags: ios, mfi

Im currently working on a app that can do the Wi-Fi settings setup process on a IP-camra. Right now i can get the SSID the iPhone is currently on but the Wi-Fi password key still needs to me manually enter by the user.

Is there a way to get the complete Wi-Fi settings from the iPhone (SSID, password, and encryption method). I have seen Withings Withbaby app do it but they are in the MFI program.

Im interested in if the Wi-Fi setup can be done without being in the MFI program? My company currently not willing to spend the money required for enrollment.

Comment: MFi is only for hardware using Bluetooth and the 30-pin connector, not for anything over WiFi. It looks like the Withings Withbaby camera can use Bluetooth, thus the MFi support, but it's not clear to me if that's required for their WiFi configuration. Are you asking how to obtain the settings for the WiFi network the iPhone is connected to? That should have nothing to do with any external hardware.